# R Filling 3-dimensional array by row

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I know there have been similar topics but they don't seem to answer my problem. I have a 3-dimensional array, composed of matrices (10,5). 
I want to fill each matrix by row, by let say `1:5`. 
Previous topics talks about `aperm`, but here's the problem : since my matrices are not symmetric, when I first fill them by column as follows :

```
kappa=array(0,dim=c(10,5,2))
kappa[1:10,,1]=1:5
kappa[,,1]


      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    2    2    2    2    2
 [8,]    3    3    3    3    3
 [9,]    4    4    4    4    4
[10,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Since the column dimension is lower than the row dim, the sequence is replicated. So when I `aperm` the result, it gives :

```
aperm(kappa[,,1])

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5
```

But what I want instead is

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: Declare `kappa` to be `5,10,2` (i.e. the two dimensions reversed), fill it with whatever and then use `kappa<-aperm(kappa,c(2,1,3))`.

Comment: One solution I've just thought of, is to `aperm` the matrix first in a temporary variable, fill it by `1:5` then `aperm` it again and store it in the original matrix.

Comment: @nicola I can't declare `kappa` as `5,10,2` because I use it in calculations beforehand

Comment: It's not much clear what you meant with the last comment (and what you can't do: can't you create an array with known dimensions?), but you can do that in so many ways. Another way is, for instance, `kappa[,,1]<-rep(1:5,each=dim(kappa)[1])`.

Comment: What I wanted to say, is that I need kappa to be the way I described earlier, because I use it in intermediary computations. What I did is as described in my previous comment :  `aperm` the matrix first in a temporary variable, fill it by 1:5 then `aperm` it again and store it in the original matrix. It works fine